# Github oauth octokit giving errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, oauth, octokit

I am using oauth authentication and octokit in my rails project , for github collaborations.

`client = Octokit::Client.new(:access_token => access_token)`  If i use this method then

```
user = client.user
```

gives bad credentials errror, only basic authentication working, other authentications gives same error.

Using octokit 4.6.2

Comment: You get access token in a response from Github after you successfully authenticate against your Github App. Did you provide correct github_client_key and github_client_secret in your oauth authentication?